# ResultSet already requested

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlite

I'm using a java program to query a SQLite DB. I am currently in the development testing state and wanted to test a particular select query. I have a thread that I call to issue all my DB commands (producer) and a consumer thread to process result sets. The DBCommand thread (producer) will just open the DB connection, create a new query, issue it, get the result set and place it in the shared queue and close the connection as such:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + Configuration.getInstance().getDbPath();
        // create a connection to the database
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);

 try
        {
            if (conn.isValid(DB_TIMEOUT))
            {
                Statement stmt;
                try
                {
                    errorLog.info("Query Issued to Database: " + query);
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    stmt.execute(query);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                    if (rs != null)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            TrendApp.resultSetProcQueue.put(new QueryResult(request, stmt.getResultSet()));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            errorLog.error("Failed to capture result set from query: " + e);
                        }

                    } else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            TrendApp.resultSetProcQueue.put(new QueryResult(request, null));
                        } catch (InterruptedException e)
                        {
                            errorLog.error("Failed to capture result set from query: " + e);
                        }
                        errorLog.info(stmt.getUpdateCount() + " rows updated.");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException e)
                {
                    errorLog.error("Failed to issue database command: " + e);
                }

            }
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            errorLog.error("Database connection is not valid.");
        }

        closeDB();
    } else
    {
        errorLog.info("Database query is empty. No action performed.");
    }

}
```

Mind you the point of this program is to take elements out of a larger set of tables already existing and put a subset into a new table which I create for easier access. So when I query the new table, I get the error "ResultSet already requested". Note on the consumer side, there is currently no resultset processing yet (I haven't written code for it yet). This error occurs between restarts of the program too. It hasn't worked since the initial query to my new table.

> [INFO ] 05-17-2017 09:27:41 [pool-2-thread-4] DBExtend - Query Issued to Database: select distinct timestamp, machineId, ioType, ioId, subfield, value from TrendPredef1111 WHERE machineId = 1111 AND ioType = 2 AND ioId = "25" AND timestamp <= 1495027659000000000 AND timestamp >= 1494943059000000000
>
> [ERROR] 05-17-2017 09:27:41 [pool-2-thread-4] DBExtend - Failed to issue database command: java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet already requested

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are calling `stmt.getResultSet()` twice, this is forbidden .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making two request for resultset.

First is when you are creating the Resultset object.

Second while creating QueryResult object.

Pass the "rs" object instead.

Comment: Yep, I made the change before your edit. But I appreciate the clarification nonetheless.